# css - how to remove inherited style

Tags: css, html-table

Please see this : http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/. If you can see `<td>` has an inner table. The inner table inherits the style from the parent table. The inner table has borders. How can I make the border invisible or remove it? As you can see the markup of the inner table  it has `style="border-collapse: collapse;"` and I even tried `border=0`  but it doesn't work. The border of the inner/child table is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably create a separate class for the child table, but short of that, here is one solution:

```
.dataTable td table, .dataTable td table tbody, .dataTable td table td {
    border:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/6/

EDIT:  here's one with a class defined for a child table, this may give you more flexibility once you start adding other elements to your main dataTable.
http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/11/

Answer (score 6):

You could apply your rules only to immediate children:

```
.dataTable > thead, 
.dataTable > thead > tr > th, 
.dataTable > tbody, 
.dataTable > tbody > tr > td {
    padding:       2px;
    border-top:    1px solid #F5F2EF;
    border-left:   1px solid #F5F2EF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F2EF;
    border-right:  1px solid #F5F2EF;
}
```

This way, the border rules don't trickle down to the nested table. The only other option is to do a whole lot of resetting, which will quickly cause your CSS to turn into kudzu.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/10/

Comment: Why is there a red border on the rightmost part of the table?

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot Ignore that - I was messing around. The important thing here is the `>` indicating the rules should apply only to immediate children.

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot No problem, only note that his solution will affect every table within a table - meaning if you nest more than two, you're going to find yourself right back in this same boat.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take note of that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. You have changed the colour, for the borders, so why don't you just set them to 0 instead?

```
.dataTable td table td {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/4/

Comment: How can I remove the inherited style of the inner table?

Comment: By overriding it with another style. You can't remove an inherited style as that is the style the browser gives it by default.

Comment: I don't want to remove the border of the parent table.

Comment: Then make it more specific. Example http://jsfiddle.net/ymSpY/9/. Code above edited to show you more specificity.

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming you're using bootstrap to style your ui.

```
table.noborder td {
    border: none !important;
}

table.noborder td table.table td {
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}
```